# Is there a good plugin for social bookmarking on site for WordPress

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

I want to add a onsite social bookmarking system to a WordPress installation. is there any thing like this available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think SexyBookmarks is the best  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sexybookmarks/. There are some others

- [Bookmark Me](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sem-bookmark-me/)
- [Simple Social Bookmarks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-social-bookmarks/)

Comment: i think you misunderstood me. i don't need social links to social accounts, i'm searching some kind of system witch visitor can add bookmarks too and share it, on site, as the do on delicius re other system. i need some thing a lot simpler but that the direction... i guess there isn't anything like this...

Answer (score 1):

try one of those...

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/addthis/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/share-this/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social-slider/

Answer (score 1):

I looked around for something like that a while back and couldn't find what I wanted, so I started working on this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/recommended-links/

Its still at a kind of early stage, and many of the features I plan to build into it aren't finished, but you can take a look and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: i gave you the best answer also cause i like you're spirit. i guess i'll be using it soon for a project i'm working on, so maybe i could also help through the process. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook,Twitter,Google plus one Share Buttons WordPress Plugin](http://www.92app.com/wordpress-plugins/facebook-twitter-google-plus-one-share-buttons)

This simple yet easy-to-use plugin adds Facebook Like & Share,Twitter,Google +,Pinterest,Digg Buttons after post contents.